# TMediaPlayerControl Video Size

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

Good morning guys!

I'm currently experimenting with XE3, and i'm interested in building a video (and general media) player using `FM2`. I'm facing an issue regarding video scale, or rather, the seemingly complete lack of support for it.

I added a `TMediaPlayer` and a `TMediaPlayerControl` to a form and hooked them up. I then added a button with simple play/stop functionality, and another to load a video file. However, every video that's played does so at it's actual resolution (despite align being set to `alClient`). I've looked as far as i can through both the documentation and the source, and i can't seem to find any way of scaling or re-sizing the actual video area. The **ONLY** exception to this is if i resize the actual window to be smaller than the video area, at which point it'll scale down while maintaining the aspect ratio.

As an additional note, the video area appears above all standard controls regardless of it being "Sent to Back" or not.

At the very least, i'd appreciate any input on resizing, or scaling, the video area with the new `FM²`/Firemonkey2 XE3 media components. Is it currently possible, or are we going to be waiting on patches to improve the implementation?

Answer (score 6):

Currently FM2's built-in implementation does not support a stretched view.

To solve this is actually to work around this *bug*... Sorry, it will be a long post :)

The magic to adjust video size to the containing control (typically a `TMediaPlayerControl`) is done in `TMedia.UpdateMediaFromControl` method, more precisely in the platform-specific `TMedia`-descendant's `UpdateMediaFromControl` (`TWindowsMedia.UpdateMediaFromControl` on win).

The method uses `TRectF.Fit` to adjust the video size to the control's client area. This method only supports scaling down but not scaling up. So you may want to change this...

My *solution* may not be perfect but it works for me...

1. Create your own `TMedia` descendant (`TMyMedia`) by copy-pasting your platform specific implementation from FM2. (eg. `FMX.Media.Win.TWindowsMedia`). Sadly, creating a descendant class will not work since Embarcadero developers made all the necessary fields private so a descendant class will have no access to them. Make sure to copy-paste all the methods and leave them as they are.
2. Update only `UpdateMediaFromControl`:

   ```
   procedure TMyMedia.UpdateMediaFromControl;
   var
     P: TPointF;
     R: TRect;
     Bounds: TRectF;
     Form: TCommonCustomForm;

     // this is just an updated version of TRecF.Fit to support scaling up      
     function MyRectFit(var R: TRectF; const BoundsRect: TRectF): Single;
     var
       ratio: Single;
     begin
       Result := 1;
       if BoundsRect.Width * BoundsRect.Height = 0 then
         Exit;

       if (R.Width / BoundsRect.Width) > (R.Height / BoundsRect.Height) then
         ratio := R.Width / BoundsRect.Width
       else
         ratio := R.Height / BoundsRect.Height;

       // UPDATED
       R := RectF(0, 0, R.Width / ratio, R.Height / ratio);

       Result := ratio;
       RectCenter(R, BoundsRect);
     end;

   begin
     if FWnd <> 0 then
     begin
       if (Control <> nil) and not(csDesigning in Control.ComponentState) and
         (Control.ParentedVisible) and (Control.Root <> nil) and 
         (Control.Root.GetObject is TCommonCustomForm) then
       begin
         Form := TCommonCustomForm(Control.Root.GetObject);
         P := GetVideoSize;
         Bounds := TRectF.Create(0, 0, P.X, P.Y);

         // UPDATED:
         // Bounds.Fit(RectF(0, 0, Control.AbsoluteWidth, Control.AbsoluteHeight));
         MyRectFit(Bounds, RectF(0, 0, Control.AbsoluteWidth, Control.AbsoluteHeight));

         Bounds.Offset(Control.AbsoluteRect.Left, Control.AbsoluteRect.Top);
         SetParent(FWnd, FmxHandleToHWND(Form.Handle));
         SetWindowPos(FWnd, 0, Bounds.Round.Left, Bounds.Round.Top, Bounds.Round.Width,
                      Bounds.Round.Height, 0);
         R.Create(0, 0, Bounds.Round.Width, Bounds.Round.Height);
         if FVMRWindowlessControl <> nil then
           FVMRWindowlessControl.SetVideoPosition(nil, @R);
         ShowWindow(FWnd, SW_SHOW)
       end
       else
         ShowWindow(FWnd, SW_HIDE)
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. The trick is done, let's make FM2 use it. FM2 uses a `TMediaCodecManager` class to pair media type (file extension on win) and `TCustomMediaCodec`-descendant(s) to play it. Windows implementation uses `TWindowsMediaCodec` for all supported media file formats. `TCustomMediaCodec` has only one method: `CreateFromFile` which is supposed to create a `TMedia`-descendant class to play the media file. You will have to create your own `TCustomMediaCodec`-descendant to make use of your very own `TMyMedia`...

   ```
   type
     TMyMediaCodec = class(TCustomMediaCodec)
     public
       function CreateFromFile(const AFileName: string): TMedia; override;
     end;

   function TMyMediaCodec.CreateFromFile(const AFileName: string): TMedia;
   begin
     // LeftStr is for the extension trick - see later
     Result := TMyMedia.Create(LeftStr(AFileName, Length(AFileName) - 4));
   end;
   ```
4. Let's tell `TMediaCodecManager` to use our *"codec"*... `FMX.Media.Win` adds all the supported media file extensions to the list in the `initialization` section, and there's no way to remove or change them so we'll have work around this. Register our own extension, eg. `.###` with our `TMyMediaCodec`.

   ```
   TMediaCodecManager.RegisterMediaCodecClass('.###', 'My Media Codec', TMediaType.Video, TMyMediaCodec);
   ```
5. To use it, you'll have to append the `.###` extension to all media file names when assigning to `TMediaPlayer.FileName` and of course this extension has to be removed before attempting to play the file (see `TMyMediaCodec.CreateFromFile` above).

   ```
   MediaPlayer1.FileName := OpenDialog1.FileName + '.###';
   ```
6. When calling `TMediaCodecManager.GetFilterString` for a list of supported media file types, you we'll have to manually remove your `.###` extension before using the list eg. in `TOpenDialog.Filter`.

I know this solution may not be the most elegant but it works for me until Embarcadero is willing to update FM2.

Answer (score 4):

And if you don't have access to sources you can write a class helper:

```
unit mediaPlayerStretchFix;

interface
uses windows,FMX.Platform.Win,FMX.Media.Win,FMX.Forms, system.types, fmx.controls,
     system.Classes,directshow9;

type

  TMediaPlayerTurbo = class helper for TWindowsMedia
  private
    function getFWnd: HWND;
    function getFControl: TControl;
    function getVMRWC: IVMRWindowlessControl9;
    property leFWnd:HWND read getFWnd;
    property leControl:TControl read getFControl;
    property leFVMRWindowlessControl:IVMRWindowlessControl9 read getVMRWC;
  public
    procedure Stretch;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMediaPlayerTurbo.Stretch;
var
  P: TPointF;
  R: TRect;
  Bounds: TRectF;
  Form: TCommonCustomForm;

  // this is just an updated version of TRecF.Fit to support scaling up
  function MyRectFit(var R: TRectF; const BoundsRect: TRectF): Single;
  var
    ratio: Single;
  begin
    Result := 1;
    if BoundsRect.Width * BoundsRect.Height = 0 then
      Exit;
    if (R.Width / BoundsRect.Width) > (R.Height / BoundsRect.Height) then
      ratio := R.Width / BoundsRect.Width
    else
      ratio := R.Height / BoundsRect.Height;

    // UPDATED
    R := RectF(0, 0, R.Width / ratio, R.Height / ratio);

    Result := ratio;
    RectCenter(R, BoundsRect);
  end;

begin
  if leFWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    if (leControl <> nil) and not(csDesigning in Control.ComponentState) and
      (Control.ParentedVisible) and (Control.Root <> nil) and
      (Control.Root.GetObject is TCommonCustomForm) then
    begin
      Form := TCommonCustomForm(Control.Root.GetObject);
      P := self.GetVideoSize;
      Bounds := TRectF.Create(0, 0, P.X, P.Y);

      // UPDATED:
      // Bounds.Fit(RectF(0, 0, Control.AbsoluteWidth, Control.AbsoluteHeight));
      MyRectFit(Bounds, RectF(0, 0, Control.AbsoluteWidth, Control.AbsoluteHeight));

      Bounds.Offset(Control.AbsoluteRect.Left, Control.AbsoluteRect.Top);
      SetParent(leFWnd, FmxHandleToHWND(Form.Handle));
      SetWindowPos(leFWnd, 0, Bounds.Round.Left, Bounds.Round.Top, Bounds.Round.Width,
                   Bounds.Round.Height, 0);
      R.Create(0, 0, Bounds.Round.Width, Bounds.Round.Height);
      if leFVMRWindowlessControl <> nil then
        leFVMRWindowlessControl.SetVideoPosition(nil, @R);
      ShowWindow(leFWnd, SW_SHOW)
    end
    else
      ShowWindow(leFWnd, SW_HIDE)
  end;
end;

function TMediaPlayerTurbo.getFControl: TControl;
begin
  result:=TControl(fCOntrol);
end;

function TMediaPlayerTurbo.getFWnd: HWND;
begin
  result:=self.fWnd;
end;


function TMediaPlayerTurbo.getVMRWC: IVMRWindowlessControl9;
begin
  result:=self.FVMRWindowlessControl;
end;

end.
```

test:

```
var
  mp:TWindowsMedia
begin
  mp:=TWindowsMedia.create(filename);
  mp.Control:=videoframe;
  mp.Play;
  mp.Stretch;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a real stretch, I suggest the following changes to the MyRectFit function:

```
  function MyRectFit(var R: TRectF; const BoundsRect: TRectF): Single;
  var
    RatioX, RatioY: Single;
  begin
    Result := 1;
    if BoundsRect.Width * BoundsRect.Height = 0 then
      Exit;

    RatioX := R.Width / BoundsRect.Width;
    RatioY := R.Height / BoundsRect.Height;
    R := RectF(0, 0, R.Width / RatioX, R.Height / RatioY);

    Result := RatioX;
    RectCenter(R, BoundsRect);
  end;
```